# ¿Se puede hacer que un mismo boton tenga dos funciones en java?

Tags: java, mysql, poo

Verán soy estudiante de informática y empece a crear una aplicación donde en un punto aparece una tabla la cual pretendo relacionar con una base de datos tengo el siguiente código de un boton:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(w){
                int nc = table.getModel().getColumnCount();
                Object [] f = new Object[nc];
                for(int x=0;x<nc;x++) {
                    f[x]="";
                }
                ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(f);
                w=false;
            }else {
                w=true;

            }
        }
    });
```

En resumidas cuentas hace aparecer una nueva fila donde el usuario podrá poner los datos, y quisiera saber si es posible que al volver a darle click al boton (para ello la estructura if-else) pudiera subir a la base de datos lo que se capturara en las celdas de la tabla y de ser el caso ¿Comó?

Comment: Hola, no se si te entendí muy bien tu requerimiento. Pero si se te edita o agrega una fila nueva a tu tabla, podrías controlar ese evento (el de tu table) y desde ahí persistir los datos. Dejaría que el botón cumpla una sola función.
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que ponga cada función en un botón por separado?

Comment: No, no quise decirte eso, igual creo que es lo que te conviene si se te complica, usa un botón para agregar y otro para guardar.
Yo si recomendé que manejes las funciones por separado pero no en dos botones.Tu "table" escucha y sabe si se agrego o edito una celda y es en ese evento donde deberías "subir a la base de datos lo que se captura en las celdas". En vez de hacer chirimbolos con un solo botón, pero usa dos botones: uno agregar, otro guardar y listo.
Espero que te oriente un poco por lo menos mi respuesta.

Comment: Creo que ya comprendí, Muchas Gracias